# ERROR: More than one .egg-info directory found in /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-<somehash>

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install `advisor` through `pip install advisor` but it fails with the following error:

`ERROR: More than one .egg-info directory found in /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-<somehash>`

```
$ pip --version
pip 21.0.1 from /my_home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

I tried this with two other ubuntu machines; one with the same pip version `21.0.1` and the other with an older pip `20.3.4`; the latter successfully installed while the former failed with the same error message. I'm inclined to think that this is a pip version issue.

Anyone has other ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bug in the package — it calls `setup()` two times: [1](https://github.com/tobegit3hub/advisor/blob/f45035318b185560c24228d0f547df6079725920/advisor_client/setup.py#L22) and [2](https://github.com/tobegit3hub/advisor/blob/f45035318b185560c24228d0f547df6079725920/advisor_client/setup.py#L29).