# Are distutils and setuptools thread-safe?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

Does anybody know if I can safely compile multiple extensions concurrently with threading?

I realise this might not speed things up (although compilers are run in subprocesses, so maybe!), but I'm in a situation where GUI actions can start a simulation which may involve a compilation step, so I'd like to know if I need to prevent multiple simulations from compiling at the same time, or if this is fine

Answer (score 1):

Not only they're not thread-safe — they're not process-safe: you cannot call `setup()` multiple times in one process. [See an example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66432640/7976758) of errors from this.

To work around the limitation you have to run `python setup.py` or `pip` in a subprocess and then the question of thread-safety no longer applies.

Comment: Thanks! That example looks like it's compiling - and installing - the same code twice, in the same location. That would cause errors you wouldn't get when compiling two separate packages at the same time (and with different paths)

Comment: @MichaelClerx There are two different calls to `setup()` so I'm sure you cannot do it in one process.

Comment: Why are you sure you can't call `setup()` from two different threads?

Comment: Because it seems `distutils`/`setuptools` have a lot of global states. If one cannot call them 2 times from one thread I'm sure calling them from different threads would be even worse.

Comment: Thanks! I also assumed that there'd be some issues, but I didn't see any mention in the docs or code about this, and noticed that compilation does happen in subprocesses already, so was wondering if perhaps it would be thread-safe & if someone in-the-know could tell me. The example you quoted doesn't convince me it's not thread-safe, as it's a much more obvious error (two eggs in the same path)